# Neo4j enterprise 2.3.1 - Unable to load NODE with id 26007298

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using cypher rest api and web return error since last version (2.3.1)
"Unable to load NODE with id 26007298." and "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound"

This is the query:

```
MATCH (member:Member)-[u:UPLOAD]->(:Photo)
WITH count(u) AS pc, member
WHERE pc > 4
MATCH (m:Member)
WHERE m.id='XXX' AND not((m)-[:FOLLOW]->(member))
WITH member, rand() AS r
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 80
MATCH (member)-[:UPLOAD]->(p:Photo)
WITH member.id AS member_id, p
ORDER BY p.votes DESC
RETURN member_id, collect(p.id)[0..5] AS photos
```

Already tried:

1. Remove schema/label directory and restart service.
2. Enable & disable allow_store_upgrade and restart.
3. Copied fresh data from backup and restart

Any suggestions?

Comment: run a consistency check as described on http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this script: https://github.com/jexp/store-utils
It copied everything and ignored the invalid nodes and relationships.